# Can selected files be added at the end rather than beginning using the OpenFileDialog with multiselect?

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

When using the OpenFileDialog with multiselect enabled, every time I select another files(using ctrl or shift + click), the most recently added files are inserted in the beginning of the File name textbox. Is there a way to change this and make them add to the end instead?

I am doing some work with the [IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to customize it and file ordering is crucial to me.

I am working with .NET 4.5.

Edit: After doing some more experimenting, I am unsure of the ordering of the files after they are returned as well. It appears to be alphabetical. Can anyone verify this? I am having trouble finding good documentation/examples for this.

Comment: And what about reversing the Filenames array?

Comment: I'm actually trying to change the order they are shown while the dialog is still open (before the user selects OK). I may not have made that clear enough in my question.

Comment: No it is clear, but what is not clear (and triggered my answer) is the reason for that. I was assuming that what counts is the code that you execute after the selection and not how they are displayed. In any case I think they choose to add them in this way to facilitate seeing the last file when you add many files and some of them scrolls away from the textbox.

Comment: Confirmed. The order of the files returned is alphabetic descending. It seems that you cannot accomplish your goal using the standard OpenFileDialog. If you don't need to change folder then it is relatively easy to prepare a list with your custom selection of the files.

Comment: You are exactly right. We are doing very specific operations on the files returned (they end up being used in pairs, so basically 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b would be the format needed). I'm not sure if it is even possible to get this with what Microsoft currently provides.

Comment: Another thing to note is if you change the ordering in the dialog while it is open, that will be the order the array is returned after the dialog is closed. So if you organize by file type than the selected items array will be ordered by file type as well. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Revised my answer to show how to use a ListView to keep the selection order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get your selected files in the exact order in which you click them, you cannot use the standard OpenFileDialog because you cannot control the order of the returned FileNames property. 
Instead you could easily build your own ListView of files in a particular folder and keep track by yourself of the order of the items clicked adding and removing them from a `List<string>`

```
 List<string> filesSelected = new List<string>();
```

Suppose, for example to have a ListView with these properties

```
// Set the view to show details.
listView1.View = View.Details;

// Display check boxes.
listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.MultiSelect = false;

// Set the handler for tracking the check on files and their order
listView1.ItemCheck += onCheck;

// Now extract the files, (path fixed here, but you could add a 
// FolderBrowserDialog to allow changing folders....
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\temp");
FileInfo[] entries = di.GetFiles("*.*");

// Fill the listview with files and some of their properties
ListViewItem item = null;
foreach (FileInfo entry in entries)
{
    item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { entry.Name, entry.LastWriteTime.ToString(), entry.Length.ToString()} );
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}            
listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);                        

// Create columns for the items and subitems.
// Width of -2 indicates auto-size.
listView1.Columns.Add("File name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Last Write Time2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Size", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

At this point the onCheck event handler could be used to add and remove the files from the list of tracked files

```
void onCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index != -1)
    {
        string file = listView1.Items[e.Index].Text;
        if (filesSelected.Contains(file))
            filesSelected.Remove(file);
        else
            filesSelected.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I think this is the best I can do with what the OpenFileDialog allows.